# Cannot fix: ! LaTeX Error: File `pdflscape.sty' not found

Tags: packages, installing, r, rstudio, tinytex

I am using tinytex, Windows 10, R Studio

```
install.packages("tinytex")
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

and keep seeing the following error when I try to run a .Rmd file which contains \usepackage{pdflscape}

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pdflscape.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Report_Gen.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Report_Gen.log for more info.
```

Not only do I keep getting this error for pdflscape, but also for other packages the .Rmd file uses, such as pagecolor, titling, sectsty, fancyhdr.

I have tried

```
tinytex::parse_install(
    text = "! LaTeX Error: File `pdflscape.sty' not found."
)
```

which gives the error

```
Warning message:
In parse_packages(...) :
  Failed to find a package that contains pdflscape.sty
```

Doing this

```
tinytex::tlmgr_install('pdflscape.sty')
```

gives me the following

```
C:\Users\...........: TLPDB::from_file could not initialize from: https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
C:\Users\...........: Maybe the repository setting should be changed.
C:\Users\...........: More info: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html
```

Which I can't really make sense of, except to blindly follow the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227177/cannot-install-tinytex-package-maybe-the-repository-setting-should-be-changed) question. Yet after typing

```
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/CTAN/')
```

into R and repeating all the above steps, and again doing this after typing in

```
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = 'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/')
```

I still get the same error as before. Any help?

Comment: can't really help with the R parts but the URL for tlmgr should normally be something like `https://mirror.example.org/ctan/path/systems/texlive/tlnet`  (that is, ending in `tlnet` not in `CTAN` or `tex-archive`)